# How to resolve Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)?

Tags: ssh, centos, google-compute-engine, gcloud

This question may have been asked before but I don't understand the concept. Can you please help me here?

Weird issue from this morning .. see i just push my file to google cloud computing then showing below error.. I don't know where to look that error.

```
ri@ri-desktop:~$ gcloud compute --project "project" ssh --zone "europe-west1-b" "instance"
Warning: Permanently added '192.xx.xx.xx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

Comment: Have you created and set up an ssh key for use with this service?

Comment: @EtanReisner Till this morning working fine .. ! but i can't figure out what cause this issue .. ? can you guide me .. !

Comment: Did you change anything this morning? Is your key still there? Are the permissions still correct on it? Can you get that ssh command to give you more verbose output (like `ssh -vvv` for normal ssh)?

Comment: Nope .. not that i aware of .. seems like lot of error in ssh -vvv <ip>  ..

Comment: There shouldn't be "a lot of error"s in that output but there may be a bunch of negotiations that fail before things succeed. Does it say it is trying your key? You can put the output in your post if you want.

Answer (score 9):

This occurs when your compute instance has `PermitRootLogin no` in it's SSHD config and you try to login as root. You can change the login user by adding `username@` before the instance name. Here is a complete example:

```
gcloud compute instances create my-demo-compute \
  --zone us-central1-f \
  --machine-type f1-micro \
  --image-project debian-cloud \
  --image-family debian-8 \
  --boot-disk-size=10GB

gcloud --quiet compute ssh user@hostname --zone us-central1-f
```

In the example above, gcloud will set the correct credentials and will make sure you login. You can add the `--quiet` to ignore the ssh-password question.

Answer (score 6):

One possible cause is that someone else in your project set the per-instance metadata for sshKeys (which overrides the project-wide metadata). When you run `gcloud compute instances describe your-instance-name` do you see a key called `sshKeys` in the metadata items?

It would also be helpful to see the contents of the latest log in `~/.config/gcloud/logs/`. However, please make sure to scrub it of sensitive information.

Comment: I see the sshKeys entry in metadata item, and have the same problem. How could I solve it without breaking the access to other people (there are 3 of us using the same machine)?

Comment: Try run ssh with your google account email: ssh yourlogin@themachine

Answer (score 0):

I have a MacBook after facing with same problem, I re-created my SSH key in this format and works fine.

1. Generate your key with:

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -C your_username

2. Copy the key and paste the ssh key under compute Engine metadata:

> cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

It should work fine